# JQuery On event after element is changed via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to create a jquery plugin to do custom validation.

I have a jqueryUI date picker that enters a date into an input field.

I am trying to attach an on change event to the input field that gets populated by the date picker but it isn't firing. I guess because it isn't being changed by the user, it is being updated by JavaScript/jqueryUI.

My question is how can I attach an on change event to a field that is updated via JavaScript and not by the user?

***my plugin code:***

```
;(function ($, window) {

    var validateStuff = function(element){

        $(element).on('change', function(event){ 
            console.log( "Handler for .on() called." );
        });

    };


    $.fn.validate = function(options){

        return this.each(function(){

            var elem = $( this );

            validateStuff(elem);

        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE:**

***datepicker code***

```
$('.day-picker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        var startDate = new Date(dateText);
        var selDay = startDate.getDate();
        var selMonth = startDate.getMonth() + 1;
        var selYear = startDate.getFullYear();

        var fieldElement = $(this).siblings(".date-field");

        var selDay = selDay < 10 ? "0" + selDay : selDay;
        var selMonth = selMonth < 10 ? "0" + selMonth : selMonth;

        $(fieldElement).val(selDay + "-" + selMonth + "-" + selYear);
    }
});
```

Comment: use (carefully) a timeout to periodically check the input value. When the value changes than the previous read, do something. or change the datepicker code in order to attach a callback after the value has been updated

Comment: Where are you programmatically changing the value of the input?

Comment: The datepicker is to be removed in a later release so I want to try and avoid changing it/relying on it to do something. @George I'm cahnging the value in the datepicker JS logic

Comment: onChange must get triggered. Please share more code. So that we can debug.

Comment: Added where the field is set by the onSelect callback from the datepicker plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the value of the input element, you can trigger the change event:

```
$(fieldElement).val(selDay + "-" + selMonth + "-" + selYear).change();
```

Which can also be written as

```
$(fieldElement).val(selDay + "-" + selMonth + "-" + selYear).trigger('change');
```

Note: Event handler methods like `change()` will simply trigger the event if no parameters are passed.